# Primefaces Modal confirmDialog has unwanted background

Tags: primefaces

I have implemented a Primefaces modal confirmDialog box with my:
 `<p:confirmDialog modal="true" appendToBody="true"/>`.
However when my pop up box appears as a modal box i get some diagonal semi transparent lines on my background. Could you please tell how to remove it.

Comment: Can you share the image of how is your modal box appearing! It is a `CSS style` which we need to change.

Comment: Please post theme, and version and pf version to. Try different themes, check what css causes this. Lots of things you can and should do yourself

Comment: Hi Guys, i guess i you people are right, I should check my css.

Comment: Guys I have checked my custom made CSS files. I wanted to know whether the inbuilt CSS files of primefaces could cause the issue . My pf version is 2.2.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adjust the `background` attribute in the CSS `.ui-widget-overlay` class.

Comment: I doubt it, the same settings are working fine on other pages.